# Uploading files in chunks with Fine Uploader, I fail to merge them back together

Tags: c#, asp.net, fine-uploader

I'm in the process of experimenting with Fine Uploader in order to implement it in our website.
I really love the chunking and resume feature, but I'm experiencing some problems putting the files back together server side; they're corrupt after I do so.
After some investigation I found out that each chunk is 194 bytes too large which makes that the resulting file is  x 194 bytes too large.
Is this a known problem? If need be I will post my code.
Thanks for your time.

*EDIT* Here is my sscce. I forgot to specify I'm using ASP.NET C#.

*The initialisation of the uploader on the webpage*

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: 'UploadHandler.ashx',
            forceMultipart: true            
        },        
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true
        },
        callbacks: {
            onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
                document.getElementById('triggerUpload').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }            
        }

    });
});
```

And the server side handler (c#):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="UploadHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
{
    private int completed;

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;

        string partIndex = request.Params["qqpartindex"];
        int totalParts = Convert.ToInt32(request.Params["qqtotalparts"]);        
        String filename = request.Params["qqfilename"];
        String totalFileSizeName = request.Params["qqtotalfilesize"];

        string uploadedTemp = context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + "TEMP/");
        string uploadedLocation = context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");

        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(uploadedTemp, partIndex + ".tmp");

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            System.IO.Stream inputStream = request.InputStream;

            using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            {
                inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
        completed = 0;

        if (partIndex.Equals(Convert.ToString(totalParts - 1))) // all chunks have arrived
        {
            mergeTempFiles(uploadedTemp, uploadedLocation, filename);
            completed = 1;

        }       
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write("{\"success\":true, \"completed\": " + completed +"}");

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void mergeTempFiles(string pathOrigin, string pathToSave, string filename)
    {
        string[] tmpfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathOrigin, "*.tmp");

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathToSave))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);
        }
        System.IO.FileStream outPutFile = new System.IO.FileStream(pathToSave + filename, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        foreach (string tempFile in tmpfiles)
        {   
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            System.IO.FileStream inputTempFile = new System.IO.FileStream(tempFile, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            while ((bytesRead = inputTempFile.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                outPutFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            inputTempFile.Close();
            //System.IO.File.Delete(tempFile);
        }
        outPutFile.Close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: `If need be I will post my code. ` yes please do

Comment: I added them. I also noticed that the chunks aren't always 194 bytes too large, this number is variable, but they're always just a tad too big, resulting in a file a few kilobytes larger than the original, thus corrupt

Comment: Are you sure you are assembling the parts in the correct order?  Not doing this would certianly result in a corrupt file.  Glancing at your code, it does not look like you are paying attention to the order of these parts in  your merge method.

Comment: Using breakpoint debugging I verified already, they are processed in the right order. To be absolutely certain I added a sort to the array,  same result. I find it quite strange that the resulting file is larger than the original...

Comment: @Dyte - You'll need to provide more information, such as very specific reproduction steps, the browser you are using, the version of Fine Uploader, etc.  I'm quite certain that chunking works as expected, so I'm guessing that something else is going on here.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome, Firefox, IE (latest versions), and I'm using the lastest version (3.4.1) of fine uploader.
To reproduce the problem, it suffices to set up a new .NET website, add the fineuploader js and css references to Default.aspx, initialize the uploader using the js code I provided, and handle the uploads using my UploadHandler handler. (after creating the folder App_Data/TEMP in the website root)

I've been searching for hours and hours on this, it really beats me..

Comment: These are my includes in my aspx page:
    <link href="fineuploader-3.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="fineuploader-3.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: No ideas? I think I'm going to try to set up the servlet from the sample code.. but that's a bit of a detour cause our applications run on IIS.

Comment: @RayNicholus: Are fine uploader developers available to write a piece of server software for us against a commission? Thanks!

Comment: @Dyte Not at this time.  We simply don't have enough staff members to handle that sort of thing right now.  However, we are hiring more developers to assist with Fine Uploader.  Once we have brought more staff onboard, we will be providing more specific server-side support in a variety of languages.  Until then, please reference [the server-side examples](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server) and/or post questions for your server-side language of choice in Stackoverflow under the appropriate tag(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the way I was parsing the inputstream (in my c# handler class) for the individual chunks from the request object,

The way I was reading it:

```
System.IO.Stream inputStream = request.InputStream;
```

The way it should be read:

```
System.IO.Stream inputStream = request.Files[0].InputStream;
```

[This google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fineuploader/x0TaDx4mkDo/ldhY9v3NrJ4J) suggested that the second way should only be done in IE, and the first way in all other browsers, but I found out it's like this in all browsers.

Comment: I tried both, but can't able to open file after upload. Any suggestion please. I am using this file uploader https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow